# Add default value to label MVC .NET

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, label, default

I need to add the default value `0` in case the user doesn't do it.

I have this code right now, how can I change it ?

```
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.prop.PropertyId, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.TextBoxPlaceHolderFor(m => m.prop.PropertyId, new { @class = "span input-xlarge" })                
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.prop.PropertyId)
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to set a value for the label?

Maybe you want to set it to your textbox? There is no standard TextBoxPlaceHolderFor helper but you can use regular TextBoxFor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.prop.PropertyId, new { placeholder = "0" })
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: jaja yes of course, it was a lapsus :) thanks for the answer!